# Localstorage history of searches multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a question regarding this code:

```
 $('#hledat').click(function() {

  var test = $('#mesto').val();
  localStorage.setItem("test", test);
  });

  $('#val').text(localStorage.getItem("test"));
```

it works great but i need to make multiple searches history - for example, last 5 searches - and show them. Like this, but it is only showing 1 last search. Any idea?

Comment: `localStorage` stores a key-value pair, there is no ordering to those items. The only thing you could do is purposely add some time stamp data into the items you want to search, store that into an array and add it to `localStorage` and then sort by your time stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` only stores a single key/value pair at a time. If you want to store multiple values in a single key, and in order, you could place a serialised array within `localStorage` which you can deserialise and amend as required. Try this:

```js
$('#hledat').click(function() {
  addToHistory($('#mesto').val());
});

$('#val').text(getHistory()[0] || ''); // shows latest item

var getHistory = function() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("test")) || [];
}

var addToHistory = function(value) {
  var history = getHistory();
  history.unshift(value);
  localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(history.slice(0, 5)));
}
```

Comment: Ty for answer i tried and got error: getHistory is not a function

Comment: Any solution please?